# WPF ListBox selection issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing application with bunch of custom controls.
I have a custom control with ListBox which contains a collection of other custom controls.

Here are control templates for these 2 custom controls (container and element)

Container (Inherits Control) :

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Container}">
<Border Background="LightBlue"
        BorderBrush="RoyalBlue"
        BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5">                                               
    <StackPanel>                                                    
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Name}" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Items}">
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Element (Inherits ListBoxItem):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Element}">
    <Border IsHitTestVisible="True" >                        
        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding ElementName}" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Problem is that I can't select any of this elements in containers listbox (Something wrong with HitTest).

Is there any way to make items selectable or something like that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the ItemsTemplate for the ListBox as explained down instead of using an explicit ControlTemplate.

[ItemsControl.ItemTemplate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx)